# Is EASA B1 equivalent to DCAM B1?

Tags: flight-training, easa, pilot-certification

I am from Bangladesh. Bangladesh has EASA 147 approval.

- Is EASA B1 equivalent to DCAM B1?
- Will Bangladesh accept the license?
- If I want to convert the DCAM license to EASA license what do I have
  to do?
- About type training, from which country should I get the training?